# System freezes when I play a Flash game ( like Zynga poker ) with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: windows-xp, flash, firefox

The system is `Windows XP` service pack 3. The RAM is 992 Mo, the processor is Pentium IV 2.4GHz. I always make an update of Flash when a notification of an update appears.
I launch `Mozilla Firefox` , which is of version 5 and I open `Facebook`. I play Zynga poker , which is a Flash game, in Facebook. When playing Zynga poker then after few minutes the system freezes.

So how to remove this freeze ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the **Task Manager** processes list when you are using Firefox/Flash? How much resources is your computer using when this happens?

Comment: Try the latest version of [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable), and let me know if you have the same problem. It may be an issue with your Firefox installation or profile.

Comment: I prefer not make such an installation because the computer I am using is my office computer. So I will not take any risk to corrupt it.

Comment: Firefox Portable installs to a self-contained folder. It's purpose is to to be used on any Windows PC, with any user privileges. I recommend this approach for troubleshooting web browser issues, because it is easy and safe. If Firefox Portable works well on your PC, then Firefox can be fixed to work well, too.

Comment: Will there be any conflicts with the already installed Mozilla Firefox ?

Comment: None at all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the *system* freezing, try [disabling hardware acceleration](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html) in Flash Player.  Maybe bad video drivers are causing the system to lock up.